# Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string' in Angular 12 template

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an interface with few optional properties

```
export interface NavigationItem {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  classes?: string;
  badge?: {
    title?: string;
    translate?: string;
    bg?: string;
    fg?: string;
  };
}
```

In the template, when passing value to input properties

```
<span *ngIf="item?.badge" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': item?.badge?.bg,'color': item?.badge?.fg}"
          [translate]="item?.badge?.translate"
          class="nav-link-badge">
            {{item?.badge?.title}}
        </span>
```

It is giving error

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

Comment: I think `bg` `fg` `translate` not accept questions mark in interface. Try remove it

Comment: These are the optional fields. If I remove `?` from the interface, it will invalidate the data. `[translate]` accepts only `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to assign a empty string `''` if `item?.badge?.bg` or `item?.badge?.fg` is undefined. e.g. `item?.badge?.bg || ''`

You can also change `''` to some default value you want. e.g. `item?.badge?.bg || 'black'`

May be you need to do it for `item?.badge?.translate` as well.

```
<span *ngIf="item?.badge" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': item?.badge?.bg || '', 'color': item?.badge?.fg || '' }"
          [translate]="item?.badge?.translate"
          class="nav-link-badge">
            {{item?.badge?.title}}
</span>
```